# Fix memory consumption of a go program with goroutines

Tags: go, memory-management, heap-memory, goroutine, memory-pool

I am working on a problem that involves a producer-consumer pattern. I have one producer who produces the task and 'n' consumers that consumes the task. A consumer task is to read some data from a file and then upload that data to S3. One consumer can read up to xMB(8/16/32) of data and then uploads it to s3. keeping all the data in memory was causing memory consumption that was more than what is expected from the program so I switched to reading the data from file and then writing it to some temporary file and then uploading the file to S3, though this performed better in terms of memory but CPU took a hit. I wonder if there is any way to allocate a fixed size of memory once and then use it among different goroutines?
What I would want is that if I have 4 goroutines then I can allocate 4 different array of xMB and then use the same array in each goroutine invocation, so that a goroutine doesn't allocate for memory every time and also doesn't depend on GC to free the memory?

Edit: Adding a crux of my code. My go consumer looks like:

```
type struct Block {
   offset int64
   size int64
}

func consumer (blocks []Block) {
   var dataArr []byte
   for _, block := range blocks {
      data := file.Read(block.offset, block.size)
      dataArr = append(dataArr, data)
   }
   upload(dataArr)  
}
```

I read the data from file based on Blocks, this block can contain several small chunks limited by xMB or one big chunk of xMB.

Edit2: Tried sync.Pool based on suggestions in comment. but I did not see any improvement in memory consumption. Am I doing something wrong?

```
var pool *sync.Pool
func main() {
  pool = &sync.Pool{
    New: func()interface{} {
        return make([]byte, 16777216)
    },
  }
  for i:=0; i < 4; i++ {
     // blocks is 2-d array each index contains array of blocks.
     go consumer(blocks[i])
  }
 
}
  
go consumer(blocks []Blocks) {
    var dataArr []byte
    d := pool.(Get).([]byte)
    for _, block := range blocks {
     file.Read(block.offset,block.size,d[block.offset:block.size])
    }
    upload(data)  
    pool.put(data)
}
```

Comment: You can stream the file using a small buffer.

Comment: We cannot help with code we cannot see, but nearly every API like this provides a way to stream the data to prevent you from having to buffer the entire file.

Comment: @BurakSerdar how do I stream among n goroutines? i want to maximise the throughput so I am dividing the work with different goroutines.

Comment: You don't need to read the whole file and then write it. There should be an s3 upload API that gets an io.Reader, so you can stream the file. You are limited with your network bandwidth, so you may not get much of a throughput improvement if you divide it up among multiple goroutines.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I did consider using the io.Reader option but my problem is that I need to read data defined by a Block(please check the latest edit in question) and after reading that data I would need to encrypt that block and that could result in changing the size of the data read and the reader function only accepts the data to be read of a certain length. io.Read could divide the block further an hence I won't be able to encrypt that whole block that has to be consumed by the other service.

Comment: Use io.Pipe. Read data in chunks, write to the pipe. Use the reader end of the pipe to upload.

Comment: @JimB I understand that. it was difficult adding full code, so I have made an edit and added the crux of code.

Comment: Everyone mentioning streaming is definitely correct. Just to answer "I wonder if there is any way to allocate a fixed size of memory once and then use it among different goroutines?", what you're looking for is probably [`sync.Pool`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Pool).

Comment: @Adrian Hey I tried sync.Pool based on your suggestion but I did not see any improvement in memory consumption. is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SA6002](https://staticcheck.io/docs/checks#SA6002) of StaticCheck, about `sync.Pool`. You can also use `pprof` tool.